# Will eslint 'legacy' rules be discontinued?

Tags: legacy, eslint

Why are certain rules like max-params and max-statements classified as "legacy" in http://eslint.org/docs/rules/ . Will they be deprecated? Will they change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, ESLint early on was shooting for feature parity with JSHint/JSLint. Most of legacy rules only exist in JSLint and not in JSHint, that's why they were marked as legacy (JSLint is older then JSHint).